# Plotting R graphs using database results

Tags: mysql, r

I can successfully get results from MySQL using `data=fetch(rs)` and that gives me results like this:

```
         ID BuildingCode AccessTime
  438235588       TEST-1   14:40:59
  438445583       TEST-1   07:45:00
  438465587       TEST-2   20:10:59
  438476583       TEST-3   09:50:00
  407233584       TEST-3   07:30:59
```

What I would like to do is put each piece of data into a variable so I can use it to plot an R graph.

For example: I would like to plot a graph that shows BuildingCode vs AccessTime to see what time the building is most accessed.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "piece of data"? That looks to me like one of the staples of R: the `data.frame`. You can access columns with, for example: `data$BuildingCode`, or equivalently, `data[[2]]`, `data[['BuildingCode']]`, `data[, 'BuildingCode']`, or `data[, 2]`. Then take a look at `?plot`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited my code and it now prints each DB row separately. I want to create a graph so I need to use BuildingCode as one axis and AccessTime as the other axis. I am, however, not entirely sure how I would use the information from the DB so populate the graph? My initial idea was using variables hence my question but thinking about it that wont work!

Comment: graph using what? php , javascript ..?

Comment: @raheel: It's tagged with `r`, and the title is "Plotting R graphs...". ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of this is covered in basic R texts, and in the info presented in `?'['` and `?plot`.

```
# Recreate your data
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='ID BuildingCode AccessTime
  438235588       TEST-1   14:40:59
  438445583       TEST-1   07:45:00
  438465587       TEST-2   20:10:59
  438476583       TEST-3   09:50:00
  407233584       TEST-3   07:30:59')

# Convert AccessTime to a datetime object - see ?strptime and ?as.POSIXlt
d$AccessTime <- strptime(d$AccessTime, '%X')

# Create your plot - see ?plot
plot(d$AccessTime, d$BuildingCode, yaxt='n', xlab='Access Time', 
     ylab='Building Code')

# We suppressed the y-axis in the plot call. Add it axis again here.
axis(2, at=as.numeric(d$BuildingCode), labels=d$BuildingCode)
```

More advanced and prettier graphs are possible, of course, and there's plenty of existing guidance online to get you going.

Note that because you haven't provided dates, all data are assumed to fall on the same date. If you have date information you can add it accordingly when calling `strptime`.

[image]

Comment: I have copied the code and I am receiving this error:

`[1] "cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'"`

Comment: @Dom Enter `dev.off()` (might have to do it a couple of times). You might have activated a `pdf` plotting device and you probably need to close it. `dev.off` will take care of that. Alternatively, start a new R session.

Comment: I have added `dev.off()` and now I get this error `[1] "cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)"`. I am using RApache and brew if that helps.

Comment: @Dom That error is fine. It just means you have closed all graphics devices. What happens when you run my code after doing that?

Comment: I have run your code in the R terminal and it works perfectly. However, I am trying to run it on a web page and only that error is shown nothing else.